# Facebook PHP API not working in AWS Elastic Beanstalk

Tags: php, facebook, amazon-web-services, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

Facebook PHP API not working in AWS Elastic Beanstalk.
I am using same code in my local server as well, and it is working fine here.

```
$facebook = new Facebook(array('appId' => FBAppID, 'secret' => FBAppSecret, 'cookie'=>true));
$user = $facebook->getUser();
```

$user is '0' on redirect from facebook with "code" query string appended.

in logs I can see line

```
2013-10-24 1:56:03INFO[FBlogin] [] Facebook Exception : Invalid OAuth access token. Code: 0
2013-10-24 1:56:03ALERT[FBlogin] [] Facebook threw exception : OAuthException: Invalid OAuth access token.
2013-10-24 1:56:03ALERT[FBlogin] [] Facebook threw exception : OAuthException: Invalid OAuth access token.
```